# UIImageView+Kingfisher in ASCellNode missing image

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have a `CollectionView` and whose cells are `BubbleNode: ASCellNode`.

I'm using **Kingfisher** as my main `ImageDownloader` and `ImageCache`. I have an imageView that I wrapped it inside a `ASDisplayNode` with `initWithViewBlock:`.

```
init() {
    // ...
    imageNode = ASDisplayNode(viewBlock: {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil, optionsInfo: [KingfisherOptionsInfoItem.CacheMemoryOnly], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return imageView
    })
    addSubnode(imageNode)
    // ...
}
```

First time, image is downloaded and displayed properly, but after scroll and redisplay, the image is gone and only background color is displayed.

**The Point is when I tap on the rect, it displays the image!**

[image]

Comment: You should set image inside the 'cellforitematindexpath`...

Comment: @user1941284 The image is being fetched from url. Have no direct access. By the way I use `ASViewController: ASCollectionDataSource` that responds to `nodeBlockForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Find a way to cache it, so then in the `..ForItemAtIndexPath` set if exist else fetch

Comment: have you find any solution....same problem here

Comment: @HRaval I switched to `PINRemoteImage` and `PINCache` which is built-in with new versions of `ASDK`. Not completely fixed, but it's far better now.

Answer (score 0):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AnswerCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomAnswerViewCell
```

use this method for you cells

...

```
//Download image
                if UIImage(named: "no-image-found") == question.questionImage {
                    //cell.downloadImage(imageName: question.imageName)

                    if let url = URL(string: serverString+"photo?filename="+question.imageName) {
                        headerCell.questionImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
                        //question.questionImage = headerCell.questionImageView.image
                        headerCell.questionImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    } else {
                        print("Bad url")
                    }
                }
```